# How do I press CTRL+T when on youtube?

Tags: flash, keystrokes

On Youtube.com the flash applet seems to suck the input focus.  Shortcuts like CTRL+T or ALT don't seem to work.

How can you make a new window ***without having to touch the mouse*** (keyboard only) when on youtube.com or other sites that have a flash app that traps keystrokes?

Comment: @bobobobo:  what browser?

Comment: Well, I'm using Firefox, but the same thing happens in chrome

Comment: It doesn't in IE. If I was to make a guess what browser does it sensibly ... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test right now, but did you alt-tabbing out and back in the window?

Comment: This actually works!

Answer (score 4):

Click outside the Flash applet.  Embeds override the browser's default keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: No but, without touching the mouse, keyboard only

Comment: RED X!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Double-pressing the Window button does the trick faster than alt-tabbing with the same result (focus on Firefox as such rather than flash on the page).